# Liferay download file structure

Tags: download, liferay, structure

In a template, I want to insert the link to download a document using Document & Media Field, I do this:

```
#set ($gid = $getterUtil.getLong($doc.getData().split("/").get(2)))
#set ($fid = $getterUtil.getLong($doc.getData().split("/").get(3)))
#set ($fileTitle = $doc.getData().split("/").get(4))
#set ($dlService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryLocalService"))
#set ($fileEntry = $dlService.getFileEntry($gid, $fid, $fileTitle))

#set($fileTitle = $httpUtil.encodeURL($htmlUtil.unescape($fileEntry.getTitle())))
##Title and download link

<a href='/documents/$gid/$fid/$fileTitle'>$fileEntry.getTitle() </a><br />
```

The code is working but it crashes if I insert a file with space in the title. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Only when I inserted a file with a filename with space the entire portlet crash..

Comment: how? with $htmlUtil.escape doesn't work again.

Comment: I think is a problem with the `#set ($fileTitle = $doc.getData().split("/").get(4))` because the `$fileTitle` is empty

Comment: I would write a simple unit-test or simple java-main-program and test your transformation. Plain Java is cleaner as Velocity :)

Comment: I'm agree! But I need to use structure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do that with

```
$httpUtil.decodeURL($htmlUtil.unescape($doc.getData()))
```

Tnx
Sabrina